# Concepts: Channel vs. Stream

Tags: stream, terminology, channel

is there a conceptual difference between the terms "Channel" and "Stream"?
Do the terms require/determine, for example, the allowed number of concurrent Consumers or Producers?

I'm currently developing a Channel/Stream of DataFlowVariables, which may be written by *one* producer and read by *one* consumer as the implementation is destructive/mutable. Would this be a Channel or Stream, is there any difference at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These terms are widely used for many and varied concepts. They are roughly synonymous and often used interchangeably.

In some contexts, a channel refers to a subdivision of a large communication medium. For instance, radio and TV stations use "channels" to describe the frequency-division multiplexing approach to separating signals. The AMQP message-bus protocol uses channels to multiplex traffic over a TCP session.

In computer science, the term channel sometimes refers to a message-oriented pipe between communicating end-points. Tony Hoare's CSP (from which Occam, Limbo, and Google's Go are derived) use channels as the fundamental unit of communication and synchronisation.

The term *stream*, OTOH, tends to refer more to a byte-oriented communication pipe, such as a TCP socket, which delivers a continuous stream of bytes or characters, without a clear subdivision that separates one message from another.

Comment: OTOH = on the other hand; just thought this might save some googling time for non-native speakers like me.

Comment: @lyomi: It's two mouse clicks. The answer is _in_ the results page.

Comment: Except of course in Stream Control Transmission Protocol (SCTP), where each thing that you called a "channel" is called a "stream."   Even within networking, these are not clearly defined, depending on the exact domain (telecom vs web, in this case.)

Answer (score 5):

The "Channel" determines HOW you transmitit data. The "stream" is the concrete data transmited  through one channel.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you are talking about but...

A *channel* usually refers to some physical construction or virtual pathway to stream something through.

A *stream* is actually that something that is being streamed through a channel.

Does this make any sense?